# is there a limit on how many times i can access fxcm xml feed

Tags: market-data, fx

i'm writing an python application that uses fxcm's xml feed. here is the link
http://rates.fxcm.com/RatesXML

does anyone know if there are limits on how many times you can access this data? right now i update the application every 5 seconds. however i am anticipating about 50 or so users will be using it when its ready. i guess my fear is that it will look like DDOS attack from our company's ip.

eventually we are planning on using a fx datafeed but for now we need something quick that works. any ideas?

Comment: Ask,  http://www.fxcm.com/support/contact-client-support/?_ga=1.23453626.1272488612.1426863181